# Make dropdown menu appear outside of navigation div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a basic website with a dropdown menu for switching languages. I can't seem to make the dropdown appear outside of the navigation div even after trying with `overflow: visible !important;` as suggested in other threads. Instead my dropdown menu appears inside the navigation bar as shown below:

[image]

[image]

The codepen for this example is https://codepen.io/mattiasjohnson/pen/VwbZbVm

**Solution (edit):**
As per s.kuznetsov's comment adding `position: absolute` to `.lang-switch-hidden` solved the problem.

Comment: add position: absolute to .lang-switch-hidden

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Hi. That behavior of your navigation div is because you don't set its `height` propriety with a precise value. By default, `height`'s value is `auto`. Because of that, when the `.lang-switch-menu`'s `height` grows, the navigation div' `height` grows to **avoid overflow**. If you set the navigation div's `height` in a precise value like `2rem`, you can see that it won't grow anymore.

### Solutions

1. Set the navigation div's `height` precise :

```css
#navbar {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    height: 2rem ;
}
```

NB : By precise value I mean a value who don't tell the navigator to calculate its height according to his content like : `fit-content` or `auto`.

2.This code, add at the end of your css, can give you another way to solve the problem.

```css
.lang-switch-menu{
    position:relative;
}
.lang-switch-hidden{
  position:absolute;
}
```